# A higher level of sudo killing a PID

Tags: kill

When I `ps aux | grep 'S'` I see a few programs that I want to `kill`. According to `man ps` the state code for `S` is `interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)`. 
I've tried `kill [Process ID (PID)]` and also `sudo kill [Process ID (PID)]`. Despite my efforts they're all still in `interruptible sleep`. *NB: I don't want to kill all (`killall`) the PIDs.*

**Q:** Is there anyway of killing these PIDs? Or an alternative way of stopping them?

Comment: Are you using `kill -9` (i.e., `kill -KILL`)? Might these processes be catching or ignoring SIGTERM?

Comment: @scott would this be `kill -9 [PID]`? And what does `kill -9` do, because I don't want inadvertently `kill` other PIDs in the server.

Comment: Oh my goodness; you're doing `kill` with **`sudo`** privileges, and you haven't read the `kill` man page! Oh my!

Comment: @scott I honestly have read the `man kill` but I've concluded that `kill -9 [PID No]` is going nuclear. So I just want to reconfirm. I've messed up by running the same program multiple times in the background, which is why I want to kill them now.

Comment: It's more like using kryptonite or a silver bullet; it's a way of killing a process that doesn't want to be killed (e.g., it catches every signal it can, including SIGTERM). It shouldn't be dangerous if you're careful not to give it parameters you don't mean to; e.g., ***don't*** do `kill -9 0`. (Don't aim a gun at something unless you want to kill it.) If you're trying to kill your own processes, there's no reason to use `sudo`: it doesn't make the command more effective, but it does make it more dangerous.

Comment: @scott, I've read up on `kill -9`, and now I understand! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kill -9 [PID value]` kills that particular PID. To better understand we can consider `kill -9` to act like a power shortage, just on that single process/PID. The PID will be terminated unconditionally - without the chance of cleaning up/flush the caches by the operating system. This in turn may result to [zombie processes](https://zombieprocess.wordpress.com/what-is-a-zombie-process) appearing, but they will disappear upon reboot. As for the resources, the operating system will reclaim these resources after the PID has been `kill -9`'ed.